# How to set the ReadOnly of entire row in DataGridView based on condition?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Not sure why setting the ReadOnly property of the row doesn't work (I am still able to edit all the rows) as I am looping through each row in DataGridView:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridEthnicityData.Rows)
{
    string EthnicityProfilingCompanyName = row.Cells["EthnicityProfilingCompanyName"].Value.ToString();
    string EthnicityProfilingCompanyID = row.Cells["EthnicityProfilingCompanyID"].Value.ToString();

    if (EthnicityProfilingCompanyName != ProfilingEntityName && EthnicityProfilingCompanyID != ProfilingEntityID)
        row.ReadOnly = true;
    else row.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

Appreciate if any one can point me to the right direction. Do I have to change how I loop? I'm thinking to make use of a loop with counter so I can use it as row index.

Thank you.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? You hit the `row.ReadOnly = true` line but you're still able to change that row afterwards? Are you positive you're not falling into the `else`?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I'm still able to edit the rows that I set to row.ReadOnly = true. I debugged and made sure that it passes through the first If condition.

Comment: @KateB You are expected to share [MCVE] for such problems, we cannot tell what may be wrong in the criteria or in other related parts of the code. But here I tried to share an answer works in a clean minimal code.

Comment: @RezaAghaei my apologies, found out that the row is being disabled except for the comboboxes and buttons in the datagrid. My datagrid is bound to a datatable and the combobox is bound as well.

Comment: As it's already mentioned in the answer, move your `foreach` loop to `DataBindingComple` event or as a better option use `CellBeginEdit` without a `foreach` loop. While the ComboBos style is like a dropdown, but it will be readonly and the cell cannot be edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the readonly property of the rows in a loop, you should make sure you run the code after the databinding is completed and the rows exist in the DataGridView. A good event for that is [DataBindingComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

But a better option (instead of a loop over the rows), is handling [CellBeginEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) which is a cancelable event and allows you to check a criteria on the cell or the row and decide to allow or deny the edit.

**Example - Using CellBeginEdit to conditionally make the Row read-only**

```
class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var list = new List<Item>() {
        new Item(){ Id = 1, Name ="One"},
        new Item(){ Id = 2, Name ="Tow"},
    };
    var dg = new DataGridView();
    dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    dg.DataSource = list;
    dg.CellBeginEdit += (object obj, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs args) =>
    {
        var row = ((DataGridView)obj).Rows[args.RowIndex];
        if ((int)row.Cells[0].Value == 1)
            args.Cancel = true;
    };
    this.Controls.Add(dg);
}
```

Above code prevents editing of the first row, but allows editing on the second row.

Comment: It would be great if you are able to review and verify the answer.